# Is a for loop like this considered bad practice?

Tags: c++, for-loop

So for this example, say I have a std::vector called original and I want to split it in half into two different vectors. Assume original has an even amount of elements.

```
std::vector<int> firstHalf;
std::vector<int> secondHalf;

for (int i = 0, j = original.size()/2; i < original.size() / 2; i++, j++)
{
    firstHalf.push_back(original[i]);
    secondHalf.push_back(original[j]);
}
```

The more obvious way to do this would be to have two separate for loops, one to fill up firstHalf and one to fill up secondHalf.

Is writing the for loop like I did considered bad practice? From my testing, this solution is slightly more efficient than having two separate for loops.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion but I don't think this is bad practice.

Comment: To use `firstHalf.reserve(original.size() / 2 + 1)` before loop can make it more efficient I think.

Comment: How about `for (std::size_t i = 0, half = v.size() / 2; i != half; ++i) { f.push_back(v[i]); s.push_back(v[i + half]); }`

Comment: It might be better cache-wise just to use two loops.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just add original.size()/2 to i in the secondHalf pushback and then not worry about having a j?

Comment: For odd sized original vectors, secondHalf will be missing one element after. Either way, if you keep that in mind, I think this is up to you.

Comment: He says the original vector will always be even

Comment: @Chachmu I guess I should read, huh. Thanks.

Comment: original.size() may be called multiple times. So, it might be efficient to store its value in a variable.

Comment: Since the compiler doesn't know if you are adding or removing elements from `original`, having a condition that uses `original.size() / 2` will be slightly inefficient. To ensure that it doesn't do this, you can store `original.size() / 2` outside your loop.

Comment: @SumnerEvans Why does the compiler not know that? Nothing in the body of the loop touches `original`. Realising that the size cannot be changed looks like a trivial optimisation to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say it is not bad practice, but it is not great practice either.

As Jett's answer pointed out, it is possible to simplify this to

```
std::vector<int> firstHalf(original.begin(), original.begin() + original.size() / 2);
std::vector<int> secondHalf(original.begin() + original.size() / 2, original.end());
```

I'd probably seek to avoid recomputing `original.size()/2` though.

```
std::size_t halfsize = original.size()/2;
std::vector<int> firstHalf(original.begin(), original.begin() + halfsize);
std::vector<int> secondHalf(original.begin() + halfsize, original.end());
```

or, even,

```
std::vector<int>::const_iterator halfway = original.begin() + original.size()/2;

std::vector<int> firstHalf(original.begin(), halfway);
std::vector<int> secondHalf(halfway, original.end());
```

(In C++11 and later, the declarations of `halfsize` and `halfway` can use `auto` to determine the type).

Whether these are better or not (e.g. readability) is highly subjective.

The essential message is that it is a good idea to use standard algorithms where the result is cleaner code, and there is an obvious equivalence in effect.   Adding an additional variable to avoid repeated expressions can help readability.

If you really must use loops for some reason (e.g. you're doing more than just copying parts of the vector into other vectors) then consider;

- use `reserve()` before multiple calls of `push_back()`
- use iterators on a vector rather than array subscripting
- precompute repeatedly used values (e.g. `std::size_t halfsize = original.size()/2` before the loop, rather than repeatedly computing `original.size()/2` within the loop).   Particularly relevant if `original` is not `const`, since - depending on what your loop does - the compiler has less chance of determining that it doesn't change in size.
- Use a standard algorithm within the loop, rather than implementing a nested loop.

Comment: Surely the optimiser can easily recognise that `size` doesn't change and avoid calling it multiple times? Of course, it can be argued that caching the size manually guarantees this (against a hypothetical limited optimiser) while also improving readability, but I'm not convinced it's needed in practice.

Comment: As I said, it depends on what the loop does.  There are plenty of ways, intentionally or otherwise, to fool optimisers since they are complicated code.   There are plenty of real-world "limited" optimisers, and simple techniques like hoisting a calculation out of a loop rarely hurts, no matter how limited or otherwise the optimiser is.   And there is also the consideration of readability - how it is measured, how much value is attached to it, etc.

Answer (score 10):

In fact, you can reduce your code to two lines:

```
std::vector<int> firstHalf(original.begin(), original.begin() + original.size() / 2);
std::vector<int> secondHalf(original.begin() + original.size() / 2, original.end());
```

**Reason:**

`push_back` may reallocate memory while the number of elements increasing. stl would allocate enough memory once at the beginning time.

Comment: Could you speak to the performance of this over the OP's original solution?

Comment: push_back may reallocate memory while the number of elements increasing.  stl would allocate enough memory once at the begining time.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this in two separate loops. This way it also works if the number of elements is not even and the loops are extra simple.

```
std::vector<int> firstHalf;
std::vector<int> secondHalf;

size_t middle = original.size()/2;

for (size_t i = 0; i < middle; i++)
{
    firstHalf.push_back(original[i]);
}

for (size_t i = middle; i < original.size(); i++)
{
    secondHalf.push_back(original[i]);
}
```

But I wouldn't go as far as call your original code a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

I would use two loops for the sake of cache-friendliness through spatial locality. In your original code, you jump back and forth between sections of the original array at indices half the size of the array apart.
It is much better to access elements of an array in a stride-1 pattern.
Also, it might be worth it to reserve space for your sub-arrays and also save other variables such as size and count.

```
size_t size = original.size();
size_t mid_size = size / 2;

std::vector<int> firstHalf(mid_size);
std::vector<int> secondHalf((size - mid_size == mid_size) ? mid_size : mid_size + 1);

size_t i = 0;
for (; i < mid_size; i++) {
    firstHalf[i] = original[i];
}
for (; i < size; i++) {
    secondHalf[i - mid_size] = original[i];
}
```

Jett's answer is very good though.

Answer (score 0):

For simple code like this, it is easy to understand what is going on. However for more advanced code (1000s of lines), I believe most people would rather have it separated into 2 `for` loops.

What do you mean by "more efficient"? Did you look at the assembly code?

Comment: He probably did some timing on large inputs to determine the efficiency.